# Is this a normal TCP retransmission pattern?

Tags: tcp, performance

Our organisation's desktop computers have been performing not satisfactorily during their accessing of network resources. Out of suspicion, I perform a TCP retransmission statistics. Below picture is what I got.

I saw that the retransmissions (blue series) are happening in a regular pattern. Is this normal?
[image: TCP retransmission graph]

The graph is from this file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZczYMCykMvtaADj0A0AuUguMcY5v0Y7w

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some TCP retransmission is normal, but this looks excessive. Looks like you have packet loss and will have to "walk the line" and check physical connections, cabling, speed/duplex mismatches. Check out the link below.

https://www.performancevision.com/blog/network-packet-loss-retransmissions-and-duplicate-acknowledgements/

Cheers,

Errdisabled